# Why can a method with a const generic boolean not call a method that is implemented for both true and false?

Tags: generics, rust, constants, implementation

This code works perfectly ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dfc0e1061f12305faf12661fb460b77a)):

```rust
struct MyStruct<const B: bool>;

impl MyStruct<false> {
    pub fn bar() {
        println!("false");
    }
}
impl MyStruct<true> {
    pub fn bar() {
        println!("true");
    }
}

impl MyStruct<false> {
    pub fn foo() {
        MyStruct::<false>::bar()
    }
}
impl MyStruct<true> {
    pub fn foo() {
        MyStruct::<true>::bar()
    }
}

fn main() {
    MyStruct::<false>::foo();
    MyStruct::<true>::foo();
}
```

It results in:

```
false
true
```

On the other hand, this code will fail ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=be0e129567e2aad60948935a2545705b)):

```rust
struct MyStruct<const B: bool>;

impl MyStruct<false> {
    pub fn bar() {
        println!("false");
    }
}
impl MyStruct<true> {
    pub fn bar() {
        println!("true");
    }
}

impl<const B: bool> MyStruct<B> {
    pub fn foo() {
        MyStruct::<B>::bar()
    }
}

fn main() {
    MyStruct::<false>::foo();
    MyStruct::<true>::foo();
}
```

Resulting in:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `bar` found for struct `MyStruct<B>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:16:24
   |
1  | struct MyStruct<const B: bool>;
   | ------------------------------- function or associated item `bar` not found for this
...
16 |         MyStruct::<B>::bar()
   |                        ^^^ function or associated item not found in `MyStruct<B>`
   |
   = note: the function or associated item was found for
           - `MyStruct<false>`
           - `MyStruct<true>`
```

I could understand this error in the case of infinitely valued types, but why for booleans?

Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One has to use a trait and generic type conditioning ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eeef86f4461a55c5cf1bcb4e6a177eab)):

```
struct MyStruct<const B: bool>;

trait Bar {
    fn bar();
}

impl Bar for MyStruct<false> {
    fn bar() {
        println!("false");
    }
}
impl Bar for MyStruct<true> {
    fn bar() {
        println!("true");
    }
}

impl<const B: bool> MyStruct<B>
where
    MyStruct<B>: Bar,
{
    pub fn foo() {
        MyStruct::<B>::bar()
    }
}

fn main() {
    MyStruct::<false>::foo();
    MyStruct::<true>::foo();
}
```

---

Of course, the principle is generalizable to other types than `bool` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=e7923ff36ac5c0242725e0fc0c5425e3)):

```
struct MyStruct<const U: usize>;

trait Bar {
    fn bar();
}

impl Bar for MyStruct<0> {
    fn bar() { println!("0"); }
}
impl Bar for MyStruct<1> {
    fn bar() { println!("1"); }
}
impl Bar for MyStruct<100> {
    fn bar() { println!("100"); }
}

impl<const U: usize> MyStruct<U> where MyStruct<U> : Bar {
    pub fn foo() { MyStruct::<U>::bar() }
}

fn main() {
    MyStruct::<0>::foo();
    MyStruct::<1>::foo();
    MyStruct::<100>::foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=09b4022d10db817edd0da02e791fecac)

```
struct MyStruct<const B: bool>;

impl MyStruct<false> {
    pub fn bar() {
        println!("false");
    }
}
impl MyStruct<true> {
    pub fn bar() {
        println!("true");
    }
}

impl<const B: bool> MyStruct<B> {
    pub fn foo() {
        if B {
            MyStruct::<true>::bar()
        } else {
            MyStruct::<false>::bar()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    MyStruct::<false>::foo();
    MyStruct::<true>::foo();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer works, but needs testing at runtime (maybe code optimization will remove it). By the way, if you're generalizing from bool to usize (or any other), you'll need more than one test (eg pattern matching). The method using traits still works for usize as shown in [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=e7923ff36ac5c0242725e0fc0c5425e3).  And in this case, it is not necessary to know and list each implementation case.